# Expected Expression in C++, but I can't find the error

Tags: c++, expression, sfml

I recently bought a book called "SFML Game Development by Example" and the code is giving me some problems.

Here is the line giving me trouble:

```
m_window.create({ m_windowSize.x, m_windowSize.y, 32 }, m_windowTitle, style);
```

Where the bracket meets the curly brace `({` it tells me that there is an expected expression.

Here is the code for the entire file

```
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window(){
    Setup("Window", sf::Vector2u(640, 480));
}

Window::Window(const std::string& l_title, const sf::Vector2u& l_size){
    Setup(l_title, l_size);
}

Window::~Window(){
    Destroy();
}

void Window::Setup(const std::string& l_title, const sf::Vector2u& l_size){
    m_windowTitle = l_title;
    m_windowSize = l_size;
    m_isFullscreen = false;
    m_isDone = false;
    Create();
}

void Window::Create(){
    auto style = (m_isFullscreen ? sf::Style::Fullscreen : sf::Style::Default);
    m_window.create({ m_windowSize.x, m_windowSize.y, 32 }, m_windowTitle, style);
}

void Window::Destroy(){
    m_window.close();
}

void Window::Update(){
    sf::Event event;
    while(m_window.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            m_isDone = true;
        }else if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::F5){
            ToggleFullscreen();
        }
    }
}

void Window::ToggleFullscreen(){
    m_isFullscreen = !m_isFullscreen;
    Destroy();
    Create();
}

void Window::BeginDraw(){
    m_window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
}

void Window::EndDraw(){
    m_window.display();
}

bool Window::IsDone(){
    return m_isDone;
}

bool Window::IsFullscreen(){
    return m_isFullscreen;
}

sf::Vector2u Window::GetWindowSize(){
    return m_windowSize;
}

void Window::Draw(sf::Drawable& l_drawable){
    m_window.draw(l_drawable);
}
```

I've done everything I can think of. I've even downloaded the source code from the book's website, Ive checked the books errata to see if there should have been a change. Other people working on this book seem to have no problem at this part and the fact that downloading the source code still gives me the error makes me think it has something to do with me, but what?

Comment: What version of the C++ language is this code supposed to be conforming to? Have you configured your compiler correctly to support that version of C++?

Comment: It says its for the most modern version but doesn't exactly specify, I didn't know that was something you could even configure let me look into that quick,

Comment: Some versions of C++ require the compiler to produce an error for code that is defined as legal for other versions of C++. You have to know what version of C++ code is supposed to comply with and you must configure your compiler for that version. Otherwise, success is impossible when you use constructs that are legal in some versions and prohibited in others.

Comment: Checked, the book says it uses c++ 11 and I'm using Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code requires support for C++ 11 features that your compiler doesn't support. See the [C++11 features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368(v=vs.110).aspx) list for VS2012. Upgrade to a more recent version that fully supports C++11 if you want to compile C++11 code.